# Converting Audio Samples to .pcmFormatInt16 showing 0s ios swift AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, swift, audio, pcm, avaudioengine

I am a beginner in working with sounds and AVAudioEngine in IOS, and I'm developing an application that captures the audio samples as buffers and analyzes it. Furthermore, the sample rate must be 8 kHz with an integer16 PCM data, but when I try to record from the inputNode and convert the data to 8 kHz, it shows 0s in the buffer. However, when I set the commonFormat to `.pcmFormatFloat32` it works fine.

My Code:

```
let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
let downMixer = AVAudioMixerNode()
let main = audioEngine.mainMixerNode

let format = inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
let format16KHzMono = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1, interleaved: true)

audioEngine.attach(downMixer)
downMixer.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 640, format: format16KHzMono) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
    do{
        print(buffer.description)
        if let channel1Buffer = buffer.int16ChannelData?[0] {
            // print(channel1Buffer[0])
            for i in 0 ... Int(buffer.frameLength-1) {
                print((channel1Buffer[i])) //prints 0s :(
            }
        }
    }
}

audioEngine.connect(inputNode, to: downMixer, format: format)
audioEngine.connect(downMixer, to: main, format: format16KHzMono)
audioEngine.prepare()
try! audioEngine.start()
```

Thanks